# Create pandas dataFrame from two other using append

Tags: python, pandas

I am preparing a dataframe from two other dataframes so I later can use to_csv to export the results into csv file ,but the resulting dataframe is empty despite that the input row of datatype `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` isn't empty, here is how I am doing that:

```
def writeCSVResult(self, indices, test_set, train_set, output_csvfile_name):
        all_columns = train_set.columns.values 

        results = pd.DataFrame(columns=all_columns)

        for i in xrange(self.testSet_length):
            results.append(test_set.loc[i],ignore_index=True)

            for j in xrange(self.numbe_of_cl):
                results.append(train_set.loc[indices[j]],ignore_index=True)

        print results.shape
        results.to_csv(output_csvfile_name, cols=all_columns, index=False)

        return
```

the resulting dataframe shape (0, 20)

Further infos:

```
test_set shape (10,20) 
train_set shape (500000,20)
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example of what you want to achieve? Your snippet seems to be part of a larger code. What are the shapes of the two initial dataframes?

Comment: @chris-sc I updated the code to include the dataframes shapes. I am also making sure that the dataframes has the correct shape when entering the above method

Comment: I still struggle to see the desired result - could you show with a small dataset how you want to combine the two initial dataframes? Just append them or do some more sophisticated combination? Your function seems to take some `indices` and combines testset with trainset data?

Comment: @chris-sc, thanks for helping David cached my mistake! problem resolved.

Comment: Arr, could have seen that.. :)

Comment: @chris-sc thanks anyways I prefer to discuss jointly with people to resolve problems faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.append(other)` "Appends rows of `other` to the end of this frame, **returning a new object**."

In other words, it does not change the object at hand. You are calling `append` and dropping the result on the bit floor. If you want to append to the frame in the sense of list.append, you need to use something like

```
results = results.append(test_set.loc[i],ignore_index=True)
```